# Moved windows to other drive, now it fails to boot, why?

Tags: windows, boot, clone

Long time ago, I decided to install linux to my laptop. I had windows 8.1 on my ssd1, with EFI boot, and I made a copy of that ssd using `dd` command, while booted from usb stick:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=my_external_drive/windows_backup.img
```

Now I have linux on ssd1, and bought ssd2 (larger than ssd1). I think that dual boot might be usefull, so I did

```
dd if=my_external_drive/windows_backup.img of=/dev/sdb
```

where `sdb` is ssd2. Linux boots in legacy mode, and when I switch to UEFI mode, windows attempts to boot, but fails.

What can possibly be wrong? If I write `windows_backup` to ssd1, than it boots normaly, but I want windows to be on ssd2.

Comment: Run the Windows Startup Repair. It needs to fix the BCD entries. The installer should fix this automatically and make your Windows installation bootable again.

Comment: @GiantTree you haven't answered (or even acknowledged that you haven't answered), the question he asked, of why.

Comment: @barlop like John P said inhis answer, it's because of differing drive signatures/identifiers. Each drive is individual and thus is addressed individually. Sometimes you need to just know that something isn't wrong but just designed to be like so. Simple Google research would lead to numerous answers to "why" this is and thus I saw no point in adding this to my comment. In the end this is just a comment and no answer.

Comment: @GiantTree I read john's answer. But it doesn't negate the issue I pointed out with your comment. You could've said "in addition to john's answer, i'd add ...."

Comment: @barlop I just thought everyone knows that comments don't answer questions. Sorry if I misunderstood the point of comments. It says right there: "Avoid answering questions in comments".

Comment: @GiantTree well it was very wise of you to not answer/address his question based on that then

Answer (score 2):

The BCD data on the drive may be pointing to the original drive's signature. You might be able to use Microsoft's Bootrec tool to fix it: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927392

**Related Links**

[Why does a cloned Windows 7 BCD contain incomplete data (and, therefore, prevent booting)?](https://superuser.com/questions/603007/why-does-a-cloned-windows-7-bcd-contain-incomplete-data-and-therefore-prevent?rq=1)